# Tokenizing the documents already indexed in an elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have some documents stored inside my index in elasticsearch. I want to analyze the documents stored inside that index through a custom-made elasticsearch plugin.

I tried doing this task using the term_vectors API but, got no luck.

Is there any way to analyze the indexed documents without updating the index mapping?

Comment: Do you want to tokenize them and use it in searching in elasticsearch or do want to tokenize them and use tokens in somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I want to tokenize them and use them for searching purposes.

Comment: As far as i know, the only way to do this is updating the mapping and reindexing all of the documents.

Comment: In general, yes, but new versions of Elastic support runtime fields which could help in this case. They are definitely not available in Elasticsearch-5..